# Change Font Color for Semantic UI Component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to change the font color of a Semantic pre-made component. I am using this component in React.

I tried adding a id and class tag to the  tag, but it did not work. I also tried targeting the entire body in my css file.

```
<Container text id="text1">
    <Header 
      as='h1'
      content='Gardenia'
      inverted
      style={{
        fontSize: mobile ? '2em' : '4em',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        marginBottom: 0,
        marginTop: mobile ? '1.5em' : '1.5em',
      }}
    />
```

```
#text1{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to use preset colors for headers in the [Semantic UI docs](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/header.html), if you want to define custom colors, Semantic UI has [its own protocol](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html) for that which are utilized with custom class names.

Comment: I tried going to the links you provided, but I get page not found error.